# Probability that product of means is larger than product of maximum and minimum

Tags: probability, inequality

Given $X_1,...,X_n \stackrel{iid}{\sim} \text{Unif}(a,b)$, what is $$\mathbb{P}\left[\frac{\sum x_i}{\sum \frac{1}{x_i}} \geq \max(x_i) \cdot \min(x_i)\right].$$ I don't need a closed-form formula, just a description of the asymptotic behavior would be nice. Numerical experiments seem to show that the probability tends to 1.

Here $a,b$ are arbitrary. As wolfies pointed out in the comments, when $a=0$, the result is immediate since $\min(x_i)\to 0$. So we can assume $a>0$. The inequality is invariant by scaling, so we can assume w.l.o.g. that $a=1$ and $b$ is arbitrary.

**A little background**:
I am studying an algorithm which has parameters $x_i \in \Bbb R_+, i =1,...,n$. The algorithm has provably good performances when 
$$\frac{\sum x_i}{\sum \frac{1}{x_i}} \geq \max(x_i) \cdot \min(x_i).$$
The left-hand side can be written as $AM(x_i) \cdot HM(x_i)$ where $AM$ and $HM$ are the arithmetic and harmonic means. Both quantities are between $\min(x_i)$ and $\max(x_i)$, so nothing can be said about their product in general.

However, numerical evidences seem to indicate that the event occurs with probability one as $n\to \infty$ if the $x_i$'s are sampled uniformly. But I am unable to come up with a proof of this fact.

Comment: What do you mean by $Unif(a,b)$? Uniform distributed on $(a,b)$ or on the image of $(a,b)$ under the transformation $f$.

Comment: The uniform distribution on the interval $(a,b)$.

Comment: I am not sure that $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary. If $a$ is 0 (as in the original posting of this question), then the sample minimum tends to 0 as $n$ becomes large, so the RHS tends to 0 too, so the result holds trivially (since the sample means are strictly positive).

Comment: @wolfies As you pointed out, the case $a = 0$ is easy. So my question really refers to the other cases, i.e, when $a>0$. Then, numerically the probability still seems to tend to 1, but your argument for $a=0$ doesn't work anymore.

Comment: BTW, in the $n = 2$ case, the two expressions (LHS and RHS) are identical.

Comment: Just share some thoughts: Assuming $b > a > 0$, by SLLN, $\displaystyle \frac {1} {n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \to \frac {a  + b} {2},\frac {1} {n} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac {1} {X_i} \to \int_a^b \frac {1} {x}\frac {1} {b - a}dx = \frac {\ln b - \ln a} {b - a}$ for some $c \in (a, b)$. The RHS will converge to $ab$. So when $n$ is large, the inequality will "looks like" $\displaystyle \frac {a + b} {2} \geq \frac {ab} {b - a} \ln \frac {b} {a}$. Using wolfram alpha to check looks good. For the asymptotic and order of convergence need further checks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> $X \sim \text{Uniform}(a,b)$ $\dots$ assume w.l.o.g. that $a=1$ and $b$ is arbitrary

Let $X \sim \text{Uniform}(1,b)$, and let ${X_1, \dots, X_n}$ denote a random sample of size $n$ on parent $X$.

**RHS**

As $n$ becomes large, the sample maximum tends to $b$, and the sample minimum to 1, so the product  $$\max(x_i) \cdot \min(x_i) \quad \to \quad b$$

One can also formally derive the pdf of $\max(x_i) \cdot \min(x_i)$ as the product of the largest and smallest order statistics (functional form given at bottom) which may be helpful too, but is not necessary.

**LHS**  $$\quad \large \frac{\frac{1}{n}\sum x_i}{\frac{1}{n}\sum \frac{1}{x_i}}$$

If we are interested in asymptotic (large sample) behaviour, we can apply Central Limit Theorem concepts.

- The numerator is the sample mean of $X$, which has expected value:  $\large \frac{b+1}{2}$
- The denominator is the sample mean of $1/X$, which has expected value:  $\large \frac{\log{b}}{b-1}$

The limit ratio of numerator to denominator is:  $$\text{LHS}  \large  = \frac{b^2-1}{2 \log (b)}$$

The following diagram plots the LHS limit as a function of $b$. Note that since $b$ is the RHS limit, we are plotting the LHS limit as a function of the RHS limit:

[image]

[ The orange curve is the identity $b=b$ ]

... which completes the proof:  the LHS limit exceeds the RHS limit, for all $b > 1$. The diagram also suggests that, the larger is $b$, the larger will be the probability that the ratio of samples means will exceed the product of the sample range.

---

**Monte Carlo check**

A Monte Carlo check is informative in checking the rate of convergence, and to confirm the limits above.

In the following:

- $n = 500$
- the blue curve is a Monte Carlo approximation of the pdf of the LHS ratio
- the red curve is a Monte Carlo approximation of the pdf of the RHS $\max(x_i) \cdot \min(x_i)$.

[image]

As argued above:

- the red curve is centred on $b$, where $b =2$ in the top diagram, and $b = 4$ in the bottom diagram.
- the blue curve appears Normal (as per CLT) with mode at $\frac{b^2-1}{2 \log (b)}$ which is $\approx 2.164$ when $b = 2$ (top diagram), and $\approx 5.41$ when $b = 4$ (bottoms diagram).

**Small Sample comparison**

The following diagram compares the small sample pdf of the two products:

[image]

when $b = 2$. This time, the dashed red curve is the actual exact pdf of the product of the sample min and max.

---

**Exact CDF of the product of the sample min and max**

Given a Uniform parent, say with $b=2$:

```
f = 1;  domain[f] = {x, 1, 2};
```

... we can find the joint pdf of the sample min and sample max (I am using here the  order statistic function from *mathStatica* to automate) as:

[image]

Let $Z = X_1 X_n$  denote product of the sample min and max. Then the cdf of $Z$, $P(Z<z)$ is:

[image]

The pdf can then be obtained by by differentiating wrt $z$. The latter was used to plot the exact dashed red curves above. I should perhaps note that I am one of the authors of the software used here.